# About Silverlight UserControl

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I Have attached a silver light user control (ex: FirstUserControl.xaml) into my silverlight navigation page project. If I wanna run the application, i need to show the added user control as startup page. How can I set the user control as defualt page in silverlight?

Can any one please give me the solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

You can set it in your `App.cs` `Application_Startup` method:

```
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify the main application UI
        this.RootVisual = new FirstUserControl();
    }
```